# Chrome putting editing text mark on my hamburger menu or button

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome

I am working on react app project and i noticed that after click on hamburger menu i am getting that editing text mark like this: [image: Screenshot 1] or like this [image: Screenshot2].

---

It's also visible on some button when clicked, inside button text i am getting this editing mark.
I tested it on firefox and edge, and there is ok, this happens only in chrome.

So my question is how i can disable this in app, is there any css property or smth ? Ty for all soulutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On buttons and other elements users can interact with you will want to apply a [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select#syntax) CSS rule.

```
user-select: none;
```